# Component painting outside custom border

Tags: java, swing, border, java-2d, clip

In this custom border class, I define a `RoundRectangle2D` shape. This object is used to paint the border. Unfortunately, since the `paint` method of a `JComponent` invokes `paintComponent` before `paintBorder`, setting the `Graphics` clip to the `RoundRectangle2D` shape has no effect; even if I issue a `repaint`. Therefore, the component will paint outside it's border, which is understandably undesirable.

So, I was wondering: how do I get the component to paint *exclusively* inside a custom border?

One approach I considered was obtaining the component's `Border` object in the `paintComponent` method. And then casting this object to the appropriate class, wherein I define parameters that will influence the clip. But this didn't seem like a "sound" design.

---

**Edit -**

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;

class JRoundedCornerBorder extends AbstractBorder 
{   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7644739936531926341L;
    private static final int THICKNESS = 2;

    JRoundedCornerBorder()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) 
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if(c.hasFocus())
        {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else
        {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(THICKNESS, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g2.drawRoundRect(THICKNESS, THICKNESS, width - THICKNESS - 2, height - THICKNESS - 2, 20, 20);

        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) 
    {
        return new Insets(THICKNESS, THICKNESS, THICKNESS, THICKNESS);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) 
    {
        insets.left = insets.top = insets.right = insets.bottom = THICKNESS;
        return insets;
    }

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                // Add button with custom border
                final JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
                button.setBorder(new JRoundedCornerBorder());
                button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                frame.add(button);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

The red circles highlight where the component extends beyond it's border.

Comment: should happen automatically, provided your border correctly reports its insets (aka: space it wants to paint into) Best to show your code :-)

Comment: just remembered (could be related or not, hard to tell without seeing the code): AbstractBorder used to have a bug in getBorderInsets - be sure to implement that correctly.

Comment: @kleopatra, I think I'm reporting my insets correctly..please see my edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ahh ... at last I got it (missed the roundBorder for some reason, my fault :-) The button is simply complying to its contract: it states being opaque, so must fill its complete area, including that of the border. So setting a clip (which you could do in paintComponent) would make violate the contract:

```
 // DO NOT - a opaque component violates its contract, as it will not fill
 // its complete area  
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (getBorder() instanceof JRoundedCornerBorder) {
                Shape borderShape = ((JRoundedCornerBorder) getBorder()).
                    getBorderShape(getWidth(), getHeight());
                g.setClip(borderShape);
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
```

Ugly but safe would be to report itself as transparent and take over the background painting yourself:

```
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (getBorder() instanceof JRoundedCornerBorder) {
                g.setColor(getBackground());
                Shape borderShape = ((JRoundedCornerBorder) getBorder())
                    .getBorderShape(getWidth(), getHeight());
                ((Graphics2D) g).fill(borderShape);
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isContentAreaFilled() {
            if (getBorder() instanceof JRoundedCornerBorder) return false;
            return super.isContentAreaFilled();
        }

        // using
        button.setOpaque(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

not an answer to your question, just another idea how to do it

[image]

from very long code

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;

    public class Panel2Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ShadeOptionsPanel shadeOptions = new ShadeOptionsPanel();
                    ShadowSelector shadowSelector = new ShadowSelector(shadeOptions);
                    //ComponentSource componentSource = new ComponentSource(shadeOptions);
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("Rounded Concept Demo with Shadows");
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(shadowSelector, "North");
                    f.add(shadeOptions);
                    //f.add(componentSource, "South");
                    f.setSize(300, 200);
                    f.setLocation(150, 150);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        private Panel2Test() {
        }
    }

    class ShadeOptionsPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final int PAD, DIA, BORDER;
        private Color colorIn, colorOut;
        private int xc, yc;
        private Ellipse2D eIn, eOut;
        private GradientPaint gradient;
        private CustomPaint customPaint;
        private Area arcBorder;
        private int width, height;
        private Point2D neOrigin, nwOrigin, swOrigin, seOrigin, neDiag, nwDiag, swDiag, seDiag;
        private final static int NORTHEAST = 0, NORTHWEST = 1, SOUTHWEST = 2, SOUTHEAST = 3;
        public int shadowVertex = 3;

        public ShadeOptionsPanel() {
            PAD = 25;
            DIA = 75;
            BORDER = 10;
            colorIn = Color.black;
            colorOut = getBackground();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            width = getWidth();
            height = getHeight();
            g2.drawRoundRect(PAD, PAD, width - 2 * PAD, height - 2 * PAD, DIA, DIA);
            calculateArcOrigins();
            calculateCardinalDiagonals();
            drawVertexArc(g2, shadowVertex);
            switch (shadowVertex) {
                case NORTHEAST:
                    drawNorthSide(g2);
                    drawEastSide(g2);
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2; // draw northwest arc
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw southeast arc
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case NORTHWEST:
                    drawNorthSide(g2);
                    drawWestSide(g2);
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;// draw northeast arc
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2;// draw southwest arc
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case SOUTHWEST:
                    drawWestSide(g2);
                    drawSouthSide(g2);
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2; // draw northwest arc
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(nwOrigin, nwDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw the southeast arc
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(seOrigin, seDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case SOUTHEAST:
                    drawEastSide(g2);
                    drawSouthSide(g2);
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2; // draw northeast arc
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(neOrigin, neDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2;  // draw southwest arc
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = getInnerEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                    eOut = getOuterEllipse(swOrigin, swDiag);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
            }
        }

        private Ellipse2D getInnerEllipse(Point2D center, Point2D corner) {
            return new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - DIA / 2,
                    center.getY() - DIA / 2, DIA, DIA);
        }

        private Ellipse2D getOuterEllipse(Point2D center, Point2D corner) {
            int w = DIA, h = DIA;
            if (shadowVertex < 2) {
                if (center.getY() > corner.getY()) {
                    h += 2 * BORDER;
                } else {
                    w += 2 * BORDER;
                }
            } else if (center.getY() > corner.getY()) {
                w += 2 * BORDER;
            } else {
                h += 2 * BORDER;
            }
            return new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - w / 2, center.getY() - h / 2, w, h);
        }

        private Area getArcArea(Ellipse2D e1, Ellipse2D e2, double start) {
            Arc2D arc1 = new Arc2D.Double(e1.getBounds2D(), start, 90.0, Arc2D.PIE);
            Arc2D arc2 = new Arc2D.Double(e2.getBounds2D(), start, 90.0, Arc2D.PIE);
            Area arc = new Area(arc2);
            arc.subtract(new Area(arc1));
            return arc;
        }

        private void drawNorthSide(Graphics2D g2) {
            gradient = new GradientPaint(width / 2, PAD - BORDER, colorOut,
                    width / 2, PAD, colorIn);
            g2.setPaint(gradient);
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, PAD - BORDER,
                    width - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1, BORDER));
        }

        private void drawWestSide(Graphics2D g2) {
            gradient = new GradientPaint(PAD - BORDER, height / 2, colorOut,
                    PAD, height / 2, colorIn);
            g2.setPaint(gradient);
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, PAD + DIA / 2,
                    BORDER, height - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1));
        }

        private void drawSouthSide(Graphics2D g2) {
            gradient = new GradientPaint(width / 2, height - PAD, colorIn,
                    width / 2, height - PAD + BORDER, colorOut);
            g2.setPaint(gradient);
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, height - PAD,
                    width - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1, BORDER));
        }

        private void drawEastSide(Graphics2D g2) {
            gradient = new GradientPaint(width - PAD, height / 2, colorIn,
                    width - PAD + BORDER, height / 2, colorOut);
            g2.setPaint(gradient);
            g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(width - PAD, PAD + DIA / 2,
                    BORDER, height - 2 * (PAD + DIA / 2) + 1));
        }

        /**
         * Draws the central, full-shaded arc (opposite of the unshaded arc).
         */
        private void drawVertexArc(Graphics2D g2, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case NORTHEAST:
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA, PAD, DIA, DIA);
                    eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA - BORDER, PAD - BORDER,
                            DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 0.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case NORTHWEST:
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    yc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD, PAD, DIA, DIA);
                    eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, PAD - BORDER,
                            DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 90.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case SOUTHWEST:
                    xc = PAD + DIA / 2;
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD, height - PAD - DIA, DIA, DIA);
                    eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(PAD - BORDER, height - PAD - DIA - BORDER,
                            DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 180.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
                    break;
                case SOUTHEAST:
                    xc = width - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    yc = height - PAD - DIA / 2;
                    customPaint = new CustomPaint(xc, yc, new Point2D.Double(0, DIA / 2),
                            DIA / 2, BORDER, colorIn, colorOut);
                    g2.setPaint(customPaint);
                    eIn = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA, height - PAD - DIA, DIA, DIA);
                    eOut = new Ellipse2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA - BORDER,
                            height - PAD - DIA - BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER, DIA + 2 * BORDER);
                    arcBorder = getArcArea(eIn, eOut, 270.0);
                    g2.fill(arcBorder);
            }
        }

        private void calculateArcOrigins() {
            neOrigin = new Point2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA / 2, PAD + DIA / 2);
            nwOrigin = new Point2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, PAD + DIA / 2);
            swOrigin = new Point2D.Double(PAD + DIA / 2, height - PAD - DIA / 2);
            seOrigin = new Point2D.Double(width - PAD - DIA / 2, height - PAD - DIA / 2);
        }

        private void calculateCardinalDiagonals() {
            neDiag = new Point2D.Double(neOrigin.getX()
                    + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45)) / 2,
                    neOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(45)) / 2);
            nwDiag = new Point2D.Double(nwOrigin.getX()
                    + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(135)) / 2,
                    nwOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(135)) / 2);
            swDiag = new Point2D.Double(swOrigin.getX()
                    + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(225)) / 2,
                    swOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(225)) / 2);
            seDiag = new Point2D.Double(seOrigin.getX()
                    + DIA * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(315)) / 2,
                    seOrigin.getY() - DIA * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(315)) / 2);
        }

        public Dimension getInnerSize() {
            return new Dimension((int) nwOrigin.distance(neOrigin),
                    (int) nwOrigin.distance(swOrigin));
        }
    }

    class ShadowSelector extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ShadeOptionsPanel soPanel;
        private String[] directions = {"northeast", "northwest", "southwest", "southeast"};

        public ShadowSelector(ShadeOptionsPanel sop) {
            soPanel = sop;

            final SpinnerListModel model = new SpinnerListModel(directions);
            model.setValue(directions[3]);
            JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
            spinner.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, spinner.getPreferredSize().height));
            spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    String value = (String) model.getValue();
                    soPanel.shadowVertex = model.getList().indexOf(value);
                    soPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
            add(new JLabel("shadow vertex", JLabel.RIGHT));
            add(spinner);
        }
    }

class CustomPaint implements Paint {

    Point2D originP, radiusP;
    int radius, border;
    Color colorIn, colorOut;

    public CustomPaint(int x, int y, Point2D radiusP,
            int radius, int border,
            Color colorIn, Color colorOut) {
        originP = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        this.radiusP = radiusP;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.border = border;
        this.colorIn = colorIn;
        this.colorOut = colorOut;
    }

    @Override
    public PaintContext createContext(ColorModel cm, Rectangle deviceBounds, Rectangle2D userBounds, AffineTransform xform, RenderingHints hints) {
        Point2D xformOrigin = xform.transform(originP, null), xformRadius = xform.deltaTransform(radiusP, null);
        return new CustomPaintContext(xformOrigin, xformRadius, radius, border, colorIn, colorOut);
    }

    @Override
    public int getTransparency() {
        int alphaIn = colorIn.getAlpha();
        int alphaOut = colorOut.getAlpha();
        return (((alphaIn & alphaOut) == 0xff) ? OPAQUE : TRANSLUCENT);
    }
}

class CustomPaintContext implements PaintContext {

    Point2D originP, radiusP;
    Color colorIn, colorOut;
    int radius, border;

    public CustomPaintContext(Point2D originP, Point2D radiusP, int radius, int border, Color colorIn, Color colorOut) {
        this.originP = originP;
        this.radiusP = radiusP;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.border = border;
        this.colorIn = colorIn;
        this.colorOut = colorOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public ColorModel getColorModel() {
        return ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
    }

    @Override
    public Raster getRaster(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        WritableRaster raster = getColorModel().createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
        int[] data = new int[w * h * 4];
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                double distance = originP.distance(x + i, y + j);
                double r = radiusP.distance(radius, radius);
                double ratio = distance - r < 0 ? 0.0 : (distance - r) / border;
                if (ratio > 1.0) {
                    ratio = 1.0;
                }
                int base = (j * w + i) * 4;
                data[base + 0] = (int) (colorIn.getRed() + ratio * (colorOut.getRed() - colorIn.getRed()));
                data[base + 1] = (int) (colorIn.getGreen() + ratio * (colorOut.getGreen() - colorIn.getGreen()));
                data[base + 2] = (int) (colorIn.getBlue() + ratio * (colorOut.getBlue() - colorIn.getBlue()));
                data[base + 3] = (int) (colorIn.getAlpha() + ratio * (colorOut.getAlpha() - colorIn.getAlpha()));
            }
        }
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);
        return raster;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas basically (excluding my person) all from [Top10 in All Time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers) are very good in the Algebra :-)

Comment: @Thomas, I found that code interesting, so google a bit and found this, http://www.pastemine.com/97q0. There you can find CustomPaint implementation. Anyway that's another non working example so I will fix the code

Answer (score 3):

How do you paint the border? Did you implement `Border` interface?
There are 3 methods to place all your border logic there

```
    void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height);
    Insets getBorderInsets(Component c);
    boolean isBorderOpaque();
```

Comment: I subclassed `AbstractBorder`. When I implemented the logic in `paintBorder`, parts of the component were painted outside the border bounds, which is what I don't want. So, I thought by setting the clip earlier to those bounds would prevent this and I didn't know how to go about implementing such.