# Java rounded corner bug

Tags: java, swing, border

I'm working on a GUI in Java, and I'm trying to give rounded corners to my borders.

```
JPanel recentProjectsPanel = new JPanel();
    recentProjectsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    recentProjectsPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    recentProjectsPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 15, true));
```

This is the output I get (don't mind the colors):

[image: Failing Border GUI]

Why do I get these red stripes in the corners? Any way to fix this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Be certain to honor the [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) property.

Comment: If you look at the source code, the way the rounded corner border is painted is terrible...instead of setting a stroke and drawing a single rounded rectangle, successive rounded rectangles are drawn, which results in the above ugliness.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a variant of the [`TextBubbleBorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556) instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

[Java - rounded corner panel with compositing in paintComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291836/java-rounded-corner-panel-with-compositing-in-paintcomponent)

this has much information regarding same.